# int-tel-input limit dropdown nations on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select for country and a phone input feel where i used into-tel-input to allow international prefix selection

now i need to change the behavior of the form

once a user select a country i can't select a different international county code

i found a way to change select country code in into-tel-input input but can't find a way to remove other country code or disable section

```
$('#country').on('change', function(){
    var countrycode = $('#country option:selected').data('countryc');
    telInput1.intlTelInput("onlyCountries", [countrycode]); // doesn't work
    telInput1.intlTelInput("setCountry", countrycode);
});
```

[link to plugin](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)

Comment: I've used the plugin before a few times, and never encountered this behaviour. Please consider running the plugin in a new, empty project in order to trace the issue.

Comment: i'm trying to limit country list after i already initialize the phone input, not sure if is possible

Comment: When I wanted to change something during plugin's life, I used `element.intlTelInput('destroy').intlTelInput({property: value})` ... it might not be the best solution ever, but you can be sure nothing will interfere.

Comment: What about `telInput1.intlTelInput({onlyCountries: [countrycode]});`?

Comment: @LeoNapoleon in my case telInput1.intlTelInput('destroy').intlTelInput({'onlyCountries': [countrycode]}) works, if you want to write a reply a mark as accepted telInput1.intlTelInput({onlyCountries: [countrycode]}); doesn't work

Comment: @al404IT Glad I could be of help :-) I created a whole answer in a more user-friendly context than the comment above, described what and why I did and added a few other notes  for others with who might benefit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin only takes options when it's initialising, after that, it only accepts it's own public methods.

To change an option on the fly, you need to destroy the instance and re-initialise it - which will clear all of it's current options and state altogether. (Note: you can keep user-selected country by storing it in a variable before destroying the instance and using it as `initialCountry` option)

To do what I described, use a public method `destroy` (read more about public methods at https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#public-methods)

Try using the following code in your javascript for this use case:

```
telInput1.intlTelInput('destroy').intlTelInput({'onlyCountries': [countrycode]})
```

Keep in mind that `telInput1` must be a jQuery object, not a javascript object.